# Bold text for specified column from listview not working

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

What is wrong with this code? The 3rd index column text is not made bold.

```
foreach (ListViewItem itm in listView1.Items)
{
    itm.SubItems[3].Font = new Font(listView1.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
}
```

Comment: Is the 4th column made bold, by any chance?

Comment: No, none of them. Only if I set `itm.Font = new Font(listView1.Font, FontStyle.Bold);` will bold all row. But specified column not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will work:

```
// create temp font from the item, using BOLD
using (Font f = new Font(lv1.Items(0).SubItems(0).Font, FontStyle.Bold))
{
    // loop thru all items
    foreach (ListViewItem itm in listView1.Items)
    {
        // tell SubItems not to use Item Style & set the font
        itm.UseItemStyleForSubItems = False;
        itm.SubItems[3].Font = f;
    }
}  // dispose of font
```

Unless you say otherwise, the default is that `SubItems` use the same font and color as the parent Item.  This is an item-level property, so it has to be set for *each* item where you want any of the subitems to vary.