# How to make column font bold in a listview using C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm trying to make the font bold inside a `ListView`. Why does this code not work?

```
foreach (ListViewItem lvi in lvTotalCollateral.Items)
{
    lvi.SubItems[12].font = new Font(lvi.SubItems[12].Font,
                                     lvi.SubItems[12].Font.Style | FontSytle.Bold);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Try Like this

1. Gets or sets the font of the text displayed by the subitem.

   ```
    using (Font f = new Font(lv1.Items(0).SubItems(0).Font, FontStyle.Bold)) 
    {

     foreach (ListViewItem lvi in lvTotalCollateral.Items)
      {

         lvi.UseItemStyleForSubItems = False;
         lvi.SubItems[12].Font = f;
        }
     }
   ```

This [Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.listviewsubitem.font(v=vs.110).aspx) is very useful for learning this concept.

Please look into this Stack overflow link also.
[Bold text for specified column from listview not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27881880/bold-text-for-specified-column-from-listview-not-working)

Comment: Check and lemme know your thoughts :)